# When I arrive to my destination using Waze, how can I tell on Waze whether the destination is on my right or my left?

Tags: waze

When I arrive to my destination using Waze, how can I tell on Waze whether the destination is on my right or my left?

Example:

[image]

I saw some posts from 2015 stating it's not possible. I wonder whether it's possible nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

On my screen it is obvious as the destination icon is either on the left or the right of the road. Have you tried zooming in

[image: screenshot]